# How do I access a nested model from view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a drop down like this on my page:

```
<p>
     <%= f.label :episode_id %><br />
     <%= f.collection_select(:episode_id, @episodes, :id, :show) %>
</p>
```

An episode has an id and `belongs_to` to a show which has a name.  In the dropdown, I'd like to display the show name.  `:show.name` doesn't work to display the name.  How do I do this?

Comment: Aren't you always going to get a drop down with one entry, since the episode can only have one show? What am I missing?

Comment: This dropdown is to assign an Episode to a Track.  A Track has_many Episodes.  Show has_many Episodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a method in your Episode class called `show_name` like so:

```
def show_name
  show.name
end
```

The last symbol you are passing into collection_select is the name of the method that you want to call to get the option text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work, but did you try `episode.show.name`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use #select instead of #collection_select. You need to do a bit more work to construct the value/text pairs, but it's not too bad.

```
f.select(:episode, :id, @episodes.map{|e| [e.show.name, e.id]})
```